# Как добавить Button в TableCell? ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

Собственно на странице есть таблица. В эту таблицу динамически добавляется информация из базы данных. Требуется в последнюю ячейку таблицы добавить кнопки и привязать к ним события.
Проблем с добавлением новых ячеек нет: `row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Text = reader.GetValue(1).ToString() });`
Как и нет проблем с добавлением самих строк в таблицу: `Table1.Rows.Add(row);`
А вот использование `row.Cells.Add(new TableCell { Controls.Add(new Button { Text = "test" }) });` приводит к ошибке "Не удается инициализировать тип "TableCell" инициализатором набора, потому что он не реализует интерфейс "System.Collections.IEnumerable"."
Собственно как можно добавить кнопку в ячейку таблицы?

Answer (score 0):

```
TableCell cell = new TableCell();
cell.Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "test" });
row.Cells.Add(cell);
```

или

```
row.Cells.Add(new TableCell());
row.Cells[row.Cells.Count - 1].Controls.Add(new Button() { Text = "test" });
```